# Facebook page posts insights, and links using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get insights for all the posts from one of my facebook pages. I tried out the expression below in graph explorer but i got an error. I managed to get insights for just one post using its id, but it doesn't seem to work when I want to get all the posts at once.

```
{page-id}/posts/?fields=insights{post_impressions_unique}

{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid query",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3001,
    "error_subcode": 1504028,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "No Metric Specified",
    "error_user_msg": "No metric was specified to be fetched. Please specify one or more metrics to be fetched and try again.",
    "fbtrace_id": "Ao79E5/rtfn"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `/object-id/insights/metricname` syntax does not translate into `foo{bar}` like other sub-fields, you need to use a slightly different syntax here:

```
?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_unique)
```